# Is there any difference with these two function closures using parens?

Tags: javascript

Is there any difference in JS using these two types of functions?  In the 2nd function, it's wrapped in a parentheses for additional closure. But does it really make a difference?

```
var test2 = function () {

    var open = function () { }          
    return {
        open: open
    };

}();

var test = (function () {
    var open = function () {
    };

    return {
        open: open
    };
})();
```

Comment: No difference, parens are there to remind you that's an IIFE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no difference, but many people would put parentheses around the function declaration because it would be incorrect javascript syntax if you omitted the variable declaration:

```
function () { // javascript parser gives an error here
    var open = function () { }          
    return {
        open: open
    };
}();  

(function () {
    var open = function () {
    };

    return {
        open: open
    };
})(); // this works just fine.
```

So out of habit, I'd probably use parentheses. That way other devs don't have to scratch their heads and wonder "is that allowed?"

Comment: Thank you STriplingWarrior.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. Since your function appears after an `=`, the parser is expecting an expression. The only reason you see `(` prior to an IIFE is that you need to make the parser expect to see an expression. If the parser is expecting to see statement-or-expression, and it sees `function`, then it assumes it's found a function *declaration* rather than a function *expression*, and so not having the `(` in that case (for an IIFE) would cause a parsing error.

Answer (score -1):

In *this* context, no.

JavaScript has `function expressions` and `function statements`.  The syntax of your example has the `function` keyword after an operator, so the JavaScript compiler knows you have a `function expression`.

**HOWEVER**

The use of the parens is preferable as it gives a clue to the human reader that the following code is an IIFE, not a regular function call.

**Additional**

In a case where you are don't have an operator, the parens do make a difference.

```
(function() { /* do stuff }())
```

is quite different from:

```
function() { /* do stuff }()
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have function statements (yet). It has function expressions and function declarations. *(Not my dv, not sure what that's about, maybe because you don't emphasize that the last one is an error? dunno)*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I am using the terminology used by MDN -- and they use the phrase `function statement`.   *The function statement declares function with the specified parameters.* -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function

Comment: MDN is a community-edited resource. It's pretty good in most places, and very much not good in others. If you want correct terminology, refer to the specification. There's a reason it's called a declaration rather than a statemenet.